# Epoll events(EPOLLET) only triggered once

Tags: linux, sockets, epoll

I'm trying to create an epoll_client && an epoll_server over TCP, they send messages to each other.

server side steps:

1. create sockets, bind, listen
2. create epoll instance, add the sockfd to epoll
3. epoll_wait

client side steps:

1. create sockets, connet to server
2. create epoll instance, add the sockfd to epoll
3. epoll_wait

now, client can connect to server, but only the EPOLLOUT event triggered once. Where should i put my read and write functions and should i modify the `events[n].events` when connection established?

full code is here: [EpollServer](https://github.com/linuxaged/epoll_example/blob/master/EpollServer.cpp), [EpollClient](https://github.com/linuxaged/epoll_example/blob/master/EpollClient.cpp)

```
// client side
for (;;)
{
    nfds = epoll_wait( epollfd_, events, MAX_EVENTS, -1 );
    if ( nfds == -1 )
    {
        Print("--tcp client, epoll_wait error: %s\n", strerror(errno) );
        break;
    }

    Print( "--tcp epoll waiting %d ...\n", nfds );
    for ( n = 0; n < nfds; ++n )
    {
        if ( events[n].data.fd == sockfd_ )
        {

            switch ( events[n].events )
            {
                case EPOLLIN:
                {
                    char buffer[1024];
                    for(;;)
                    {
                        ssize_t n_read = read( events[n].data.fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) );
                        if ( n_read == -1 )
                        {
                            if ( errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EAGAIN )
                            {
                                Print("--tcp client, read finished\n");
                                continue;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Print("--tcp client read error!\n");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        else if ( n_read == 0 )
                        {
                            Print("--tcp client read EOF\n");
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Print("--tcp client continue reading");
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                }
                case EPOLLOUT:
                {
                    if ( !connected )
                    {
                        int sock_err = 0;
                        socklen_t socklen = sizeof(int);
                        int n_sockopt = getsockopt( sockfd_, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &sock_err, &socklen );
                        if ( n_sockopt == 0 )
                        {
                            if ( sock_err == 0 )
                            {
                                connected = true;
                                Print( "--tcp client, connected to %s success!\n", ip );
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Print("--tcp client, failed to connect to %s\n", ip );
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Print("--tcp client, failed to getsockopt %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Print("--tcp client, ok to write to server\n");
                        if ( !sendBuffer_.empty() )
                        {
                            ssize_t written = 0;
                            ssize_t n_write = 0;
                            for(;;)
                            {
                                n_write = write( sockfd_, sendBuffer_.data() + written, sendBuffer_.size() );
                                if ( -1 == n_write )
                                {
                                    if ( errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK )
                                    {
                                        Print("--tcp client, write finished\n");
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Print("--tcp client failed to write\n");
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    written += n_write;
                                    continue;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                }
                case EPOLLERR:
                    Print("--tcp client epoll error\n");
                    break;
                case EPOLLHUP:
                    Print("--tcp epoll hup\n");
                    break;
                default:
                    Print("--tcp client unkown event %04x\n", events[n].events );
                    break;
            }

        }

    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------

// server side
for (;;)
{
    nfds = epoll_wait( epollfd_, events, MAX_EVENTS, EPOLL_TIMEOUT_MS );
    if ( nfds == -1 )
    {
        Print("--tcp server, epoll_wait error: %s\n", strerror(errno) );
        break;
    }

    Print( "--tcp epoll waiting %d...\n", nfds );
    for ( n = 0; n < nfds; ++n )
    {
        if ( events[n].events & EPOLLERR ||
                events[n].events & EPOLLHUP ||
                !(events[n].events & EPOLLIN) )
        {
            Print("--tcp server, epoll error\n");
            continue;
        }
        else if ( events[n].data.fd == sockfd_ )
        {
            sockaddr_in addr;
            socklen_t addrlen = sizeof( sockaddr_in );
            conn_sock = accept4( sockfd_, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, &addrlen, SOCK_NONBLOCK );
            if ( conn_sock == -1 )
            {
                Print("--tcp server accept4 failed\n");
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                char ipStr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
                inet_ntop(PF_INET, &(addr.sin_addr), ipStr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
                Print("--tcp server, accept connection from %s\n", ipStr);
                // add remote fd to epoll interest list
                epoll_event ee{};
                ee.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
                ee.data.fd = conn_sock;
                if ( epoll_ctl( epollfd_, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, conn_sock, &ee ) == -1 )
                {
                    Print("--tcp server, failed to epoll_ctl\n");
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        else // remote fd
        {
            Print("--tcp server, read and write\n");
            char buffer[1024];
            for (;;)
            {
                ssize_t n_read = read(events[n].data.fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                if (n_read == -1)
                {
                    if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EAGAIN)
                    {
                        Print("--tcp read finish\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Print("--tcp server read error!\n");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if (n_read == 0)
                {
                    Print("--tcp server read EOF, client closed\n");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Print("--tcp server continue reading");
                    continue;
                }
            }

            /**
             * write data in send buffer back to client
             */
            if (!sendBuffer_.empty())
            {
                int written = 0;
                for (;;)
                {
                    ssize_t n_write = write(events[n].data.fd, sendBuffer_.data() + written,
                                            sendBuffer_.size() - written);
                    if (n_write == -1)
                    {
                        if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EAGAIN)
                        {
                            Print("--tcp server, write finished\n");
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Print("--tcp server, write error %s\n", strerror(errno));
                            break;
                        }
                    } else if (n_write == 0)
                    {
                        Print("--tcp server, write finish\n");
                        break;
                    } else
                    {
                        written += n_write;
                    }
                }

                sendBuffer_.clear();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `EPOLLET` (**E**dge **T**riggered) events are by definition triggered only once.

Comment: if i modify the events to EPOLLOUT, when there is data comes from the peer will the EPOLLIN event triggered?

Comment: In Edge Triggered mode (`EPOLLET`), events are raised only after a significant change. i.e., after the first `EPOLLIN` is raised all the data in the socket's buffer MUST be fully read (EAGAIN / EWOULDBLOCK) before a new event will be raised. after the first `EPOLLOUT` is raised the socket's buffer must be filled (`write` should fail with EAGAIN / EWOULDBLOCK) before a new `EPOLLOUT ` event will be raised.